# How to test event handler with error boundary

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a react component that has a callback function, I will like to write a test that the console.error is called when the callback is missing.

I have created a simple example using `ErrorBoundary` as shown below, but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong, or is there a better way I could be testing this?

I have an error boundary as shown below

```
export class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
  static defaultProps = { logger: console }
  constructor(props: ErrorBoundaryPropType) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { hasError: false }
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error: Error) {
    return { hasError: true }
  }

  componentDidCatch(error: Error, errorInfo: ErrorInfo) {
    console.error(error)
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children
  }
}
```

And below is the test

```
it('should handle missing callbcaks', async () => {
    const onClick = undefined
    const consoleSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'error')

    render(
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <button onClick={() => onClick('key')}>Generate Key</button>
      </ErrorBoundary>
    )

    const button = screen.getByRole('button', {
      name: /Generate Key/i,
    })

    await userEvent.click(button)
    expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(TypeError))
  })
```

Comment: React Erorr Boundaries do not capture errors in event handlers, so that's why its not triggered. The problem is not the test, is that this genuinely is not captured.

Comment: @adsy is there no other way to test a case like this?

Comment: It is not the test that's the problem. It's a real problem. The test is correctly failing. React error boundaries don't capture errors in event handlers. This wouldn't be captured in the real app either. See https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#how-about-event-handlers

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
import { ErrorBoundaryComponent, ErrorBoundary } from '.';
import type { FC } from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';

describe('<ErrorBoundary />', () => {
  test('renders children', () => {
    const TestComponent: FC = () => <div />;
    const container = shallow(
      <ErrorBoundaryComponent>
        <TestComponent />
      </ErrorBoundaryComponent>,
    );
    expect(container.find(TestComponent).length).toEqual(1);
  });

  test('renders fallback when error', async () => {
    const TestComponent: FC = () => <div />;
    const container = mount(
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <TestComponent />
      </ErrorBoundary>,
    );

    const instance = container.find(ErrorBoundaryComponent);

    const error = new Error('test');

    container.find(TestComponent).simulateError(error);

    container.update();

    expect(container.find(TestComponent).length).toEqual(0);

    expect(container.text()).toMatch('we_are_sorry');
  });
```

Comment: He's not using enzyme but none the less, he's expecting that errors in event handlers will trigger the boundary, which is not the case. This test throws in render which will of course trigger it, but I think the OP's expectations need to be aligned first.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).